# CGEventPostToPSN not working for cgkeycode (56)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

I am trying to send keyboard event to a process. Seding keys like 'a', 'v' 't' ... works fine but keys such as space, command, control doesn't work. Here's what I am doing:

```
CGEventRef e1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)55, YES);
CGEventRef e4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)0, YES);

CGEventPostToPSN(&spotPSN, e1);
CGEventPostToPSN(&spotPSN, e4);
```

e4 works, but e1 doesn't. My purpose here is to send command+a for select all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the command key as a flag of the keyboard event for letter ‘a’ instead of posting another event for the command key:

```
// virtual key code for letter 'a'
CGKeyCode keycode = 0;

// keyboard event for letter 'a'
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, keycode, true);

// modify keyboard event so that it becomes 'command-a'
CGEventSetFlags(event, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
```

For a list of possible event flags, see the [Quartz Event Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventFlags).